# Where are the components?

Tags: redhawksdr

I am using version 1.9.0 of the RED HAWK IDE on RedHat 6.3.

After install RedHawk I looked at the video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wN9p8EjiQs4.

I tried to run through the example but I notice I am missing a large amount of the components she has like add_const_ff, complex_to, noise_source, vector_sink, medianfilter.

Should I have them?  Is there a package I am missing?

---

Adding stuff to get the checker to except my question.  I tried, then tried.  Going to try.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find several packages from RedHawk developer:

https://github.com/Axios-Engineering

https://github.com/RedhawkSDR

You can try to download and build them

Answer (score 0):

All of the components you mentioned except for the medianfilter are part of the GNUHawk library of components and can be found at https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/integration-gnuhawk/tree/master/components.

The median filter is part of the basic-components library and can be found at https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/basic-components